# Google Cloud Platform API Gateway in serverless Framework?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, google-api-gateway

I'm currently looking for a example of implementing API gateway for GCP using the serverless framework, similar to how one would use it with AWS, has anyone successfully implemented a solution like this using the framework? I've looked a decent amount for an example but the serverless docs don't seem to have an example, so I wonder if it is even possible as of right now with the serverless framework.

Comment: Have you seen the doumentation from GCP like this: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quickstart#creating_a_gateway  ??

Comment: API gateway is based on APISpec v2 (soon v3). What do you expect from the serverless framework? To generate this file for you?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm trying to basically automate this process as much as possible, and have all my infrastructure in serverless.yml if its possible, similiar to how api gateway for serverless works for AWS

Comment: I don't know if serverless.com has implemented the API Gateway.